# Get all functions and their length in a c program

Tags: c, bash, unix

I'd like to be able to analyze a .c file and

1. List all the methods in the file
2. List how long each method is in lines

IE: If the file was (Using Pseudo-code):

```
int add(){
....Function Actions 1
....Function Actions 2
....Function Actions 3
}

int subtract{
....Function Action 1
}
```

The results would be something like:

```
add -3
subtract -1
```

I've been using CTAGS for other things, but I am not sure that it has this functionality.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

You might do something similar by customizing GCC. You could easily code a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension for that purpose. MELT is a domain specific language to extend GCC.

I would suggest to measure the number of Gimple instructions per function. It is probably more meaningful than counting the lines.

You could probably substract the line number of the last Gimple to the line number of the first gimple.

Number of lines is not really meaningful (imagine a comment just before or after braces, how do you count them? And there are also macros which could expand to many lines, statements, or even functions..). For example, D.Wheeler's SLOCcount gives much different results than e.g. `wc`.

If the file is suitably indented, you might want to measure the difference between opening and closing braces on column 1.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I only care about the number of lines. I need this value for other work I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is well intended a small perl hack might be enough. Something like:

```
perl -ne 'if(/^\w/){$i=0;chomp;print}elsif(/^}/){print " - $i\n"}else{$i++}' *.c
```

Yes, this is not very precise, but it gives you an idea why counting lines might cause problems. After all C allows you to add newlines and comments pretty much everywhere.

I would recommend the gcc answer nexdoor. ;)

Whoever got this line counting idea. Please convince him, it is nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is a method to my madness. I am actually performing concolic analysis on the source code of the application. I am doing it on a method by method basis. I want to skip performing concolic analysis (which ignores comments and whitespace anyways) on methods that are under x number of lines long.